# Mathematical Description for Steam Rising from a Cup

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, mathematical-physics, parametric, mathematical-modeling

[image]

I was staring at a cup of coffee I have on the desk just now. The light shines through the water vapor as they rise from the cup. The shape of the steam is not completely random, as it drift from hot area to cold area according to the second law of thermodynamics. If you whiff your hand over, the steam swirls with a distinct center of rotation.

How would one go about describing the shape and characteristics of the steam as it rises from a hot cup of water? What branches of math would be involved in creating such a model?

Comment: Google gives a few suggestions for "steam rising from cup mathematical model".

Comment: One interesting point is that while it's certainly possible to write down a system of partial differential equations governing the flow of the steam, the system is very unstable, in that nearly identical coffeecup systems emit very different clouds of steam. This is one of the classic examples in chaos theory, which tries to salvage conclusions about such systems, which by definition can't be accurately predicted numerically.

Comment: The branch of mathematics would have to be fluid dynamics, I think.

Comment: This question is too board, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computer graphics has been simulating this using fluids dynamics for some time now. See for instance [Vortex Fluid for Gaseous Phenomena](http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/projects/vortex/) and [Cuppa Coffee](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/stam/slides/cuppa.gif) and [The Lonely Cigarette](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/stam/slides/cigarette.gif).